# Como seleccionar un elemento entre más de 55000 desde un form?

Tags: php, html, mysql, formularios

Actualmente cargo todos los registros de la BD y los introduzco en un select. Esto hace que, además de tardar un mundo en cargar, al desplegar el select muera en el proceso o tarde mucho. He intentado realizar un input con control de entrada que detecte cambios, para luego lanzar una consulta con "like" y el trozo introducido pero tengo problemas a la hora de trabajar con los datos devueltos por la función de PHP dentro de javaScript, ya que devuelve un array con los valores del "select".
Así es como está (Las funciones registro y registros devuelve los valores o el valor de la tabla indicada):

```
    if ($row['id_poblacion']) {
      $poblSel = $row['id_poblacion'];
      if ($poblSel) {
        $poblaciones = registros('poblacion');
        $provSel = registro('poblacion', $poblSel);
      }
    }
    <select name="db-id_poblacion-null"
        id="poblacion"
        class="gui-input select2-single poblaciones"
        style="width: 100%;"
        required>
    <?php if ($poblSel && $poblaciones) {
        foreach ($poblaciones as $poblacion) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo($poblacion['id_poblacion']); ?>"
                <?php echo ($poblSel && $poblSel == $poblacion['id_poblacion']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                <?php echo $poblacion['ref']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php }
    } ?></select>
```

Este código funciona pero lento, se os ocurre una forma de optimizarlo?

Saludos y gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 0):

Ya está solucionado, hice un cotejo con las provincias para reducir considerablemente el número de poblaciones, con el evento .change de select.